# How to reduce a layout size in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

I'm doing an activity and it is suposed to be small, but I don't know how to put the activity with a small size for not to occupy the whole screen, as if it were a kind of alert/popup in the middle of the screen and have a responsive layout that fits all screen sizes.

my acticity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/go_back"
    tools:context=".Popup">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_et"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/authorize"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.476"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:text="@android:string/cancel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.934"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnOkay"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/btnOkay" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_pass"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textColorHint="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textColorLink="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="109dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOkay"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPassword"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons"
        android:text="@string/confirm"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried to change `layout_width` and `layout_height`, but it doesn't work fine for all sizes of screens, I've tried `getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.9), (int)(height*.4))` but in tablets the window appears to big...

Someone can help?

Comment: If you want popup kind of behavior, try Dialog

Comment: @SagarThakarar how I do it?

Comment: @CatarinaBatista do you want your layout to support multiple screen sizes?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan yes, and it's to be a small rectangle in the midle of screen

Comment: @CatarinaBatista Search for Dialog Example. You will find how to use it.

Comment: @CatarinaBatista Please share any ui how exactly you need the page to look. If you want something that needs to be displayed in the center of the screen you can go for dialog with custom layout.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan I'm trying with Dialog with custom layout, it is possible to use the buttons of custom layout instead of buttons of dialog?

Comment: @CatarinaBatista Yes it is possible to use the buttons in the custom layout instead of actual dialog buttons. If you want I can share some snippets

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan yes, if you don't mind I appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the custom layout in the alert dialog. But alert dialog needs to be triggered from the activity. Please check the below link which will give you an straight forward implementation of what you need

[Custom alert dialog](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-make-custom-dialog-in-android)

Is this what you are looking for? let me know.

Comment: and if I want to call the dialog from a webview with javascript?

Comment: in this example, it doesn't say how to use buttons from custom layout, I think

Comment: If you want to call a alert dialog from webview js you need to implement your logic in JS using javascript interface api. refer https://www.codexpedia.com/android/javascript-interface-for-android-and-javascript-communication/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to alert user with small dialog in center...

first create a layout with

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">
```

and then after create child layout

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

try this.. hope this will help you.. Happy Coding.

Comment: I've tried to use LinearLayout but I can't put the elements where I want and the both buttons side by side

Comment: can you give me image or anything i will try to make it and get back to you in short time.. you can user Relative or any other layout instead of linear .. but try this method one layout with max hight and transparent background ,center..

Comment: I will see what is Dialog like SagarThakarar and see if i work